# Multi-network IM client with push notifications

Tags: ios, chat, xmpp

I have been using [IMO](http://blog.imo.im/post/78065991703/discontinuing-support-for-all-third-party-messaging) for my IM networking needs, however they are discontinuing their support for all third party networks. So I need a new IM Client, my requirements:

- runs on iOS
- Supports multiple networks - both Yahoo IM & Google Talk at minimum
- Supports XMPP protocol
- Supports Push Notifications

Comment: Isn't push notifications server side?

Comment: Push notifications do in fact require a server to send to the Apple Push service, but for any IM client this would be completely abstracted from the user. There would be an intermediary server between the end user and the IM service.

Answer (score 2):

The app I've used in the past is [Trillian](https://www.trillian.im/) It's a good program, does what you require, and works on all platforms. Go pro, and no adds for life, it's a small fee for a long term commitment.

Trillian also is always upgrading and updating their software, and has been around for a very, very long time. I like their support system, and they don't look like they are going anywhere in the future.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Since your requirement is iOS, I'd recommend [IM+](https://plus.im/)  ([App Store Link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/im+-instant-messenger/id285688934?mt=8)). It supports a variety of networks, including Yahoo IM and Google Talk, as well as push notifications. There is a Pro version, as well.

If you're looking for a desktop client when you're at home, IM+ supports a web interface, but I'd actually recommend Pidgin for that purpose.